# Is there a macro to get the startup project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, preprocessor-directive

I want to compile snippets of code only when the executing project is my integration testing project. I can somewhat mimic this by using the `#if DEBUG` directive but this will also execute this code when I debug the view (a separate project), which is something I don't want.

I have already looked at creating a custom symbol inside the project file but [couldn't find an option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx) to retrieve the executing project. Is this available to me somehow or should I settle for the `DEBUG` directive?

For context: I have several longer running asynchronous background tasks that should be in the background during app execution but I want them to be executed synchronously in the tests. Since these background tasks are often executed by firing of events (which I can't `await`), I'm using semaphores to block execution until the background processes are done. This will make sure that my tests have the required data setup at each moment of the execution process.

Comment: Can't `$(ProjectPath)` meet your requirements?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: won't that always return the path of the library instead of the executing project?

Comment: That would be `$(TargetPath)`. `$(ProjectPath)` will give you the full path to the `*proj` file being built.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I added this to the project file of my library but it isn't working. Is this what you had in mind? `<DefineConstants Condition=" '$(ProjectPath)' == 'C:\Users\jeroen\Github\Windows-app\Showpad\IntegrationTests\IntegrationTests.csproj' ">TESTING</DefineConstants>`

Comment: Yes, that was what I was thinking of. Maybe you should print `$(ProjectPath)` in a pre-build step so you can double-check its value? You may also want to use `$(ProjectName)` or `$(ProjectFileName)` and get rid of the path (in case this should work regardless of the location of the working copy).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: `$(ProjectPath)`, `$(TargetPath)`, `$(ProjectFileName)` and `$(ProjectName)` all apply to the library, not the calling project.

Comment: That's not what the documentation says, and that's not what I observe from a quick test in the Build Events property page. `$(ProjectPath)` does refers to the `csproj` file on my system.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: it does indeed, but it refers to `MyLibrary.csproj` and not to `IntegrationTests.csproj`. I execute the latter which tests the code in the former (and I need "IntegrationTests", not "MyLibrary").

Comment: Ah, it looks like I misunderstood your question from the start. These macros refer to the project that is currently being built, not executed. I don't know if there is a way to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use `async`/`await` for this. Asynchronous unit tests are supported under MSTest, and it seems like that would be the easiest (and least hacky) solution.

Comment: One of my calls executes an event that creates files. But since events can't be awaited the test thread doesn't account for that execution when awaiting. Therefore I am using a semaphore to halt execution (for tests) until the files have been created.